# Regarding brown butter n sugar and egg mixture

Tags: eggs, sugar, butter, vanilla

I whisked melted brown butter with sugar and eggs because I had to make cookies but due to some emergency I couldn't mix the flour n had to keep the butter sugar and egg mixture in the fridge overnight   how do I use it the next day how to melt it also it's winters here in Pakistan it won't melt on room temp .please help I don't want the mixture to get wasted

Comment: What kind of cookies are these?  Is it necessary for the butter to be *melted*, or is it sufficient for the butter to be soft and workable?

Answer (score 3):

You can melt it on the stove. Make sure to heat it very gently, because you don't want to cook your egg. Using a [waterbath](https://www.thekitchn.com/technique-how-to-make-and-use-70190) would be a good choice. Make sure to watch it all the time and remove it from the heat as soon as it becomes soft enough to be workable; don't wait until it becomes as liquid as melted butter.